# Storing different data fields and linking them in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

What I currently have:
In a separate .c file named main.c, I have a main function that looks like:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv){
  FILE* makefile = fopen("./testfile","r");
  size_t bufsize = 0;
  char* line = NULL;
  ssize_t linelen = getline(&line, &bufsize, makefile);
  while (linelen != -1){
    if(line[linelen-1] == '\n'){
      linelen -=1;
      line[linelen] = '\0';
    }
    if(line[0] != '\t'){
      storetgt(&line[0]);
    } else if (line[0] == '\t') {
      storerules(&line[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the text file named "testfile" looks like:

```
A:
   echo A
B:
   echo B
c:
   echo C
```

and it will be parsed through line by line, storing testfile's data inside line (at line #4). If the first element of the line is not a tab character, then main() will call a function named storetgt and if the first element of the line is a tab character, then main() will call a function named storerules (both from another .c file named tgt.c which contains framework to collect tgt name and rules).
What I'm having trouble with is the storing part and linking part in tgt.c; My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct tgt_st {
  char* name;
  string_list rules;
  struct tgt_st *next;
}tgt;

typedef struct string_list {
char* rules;
struct string_list* next;
}string_list;

tgt* createtgt(char* name, string_list rules, tgt* next){
  tgt* new_node = (tgt*)malloc(sizeof(tgt));
  new_node -> name = name;
  new_node -> rules = rules;
  new_node -> next = next;
  return new_node;
}

tgt* createrules(string_list rules, tgt* next){
  tgt* new_node = (tgt*)malloc(sizeof(target));
  new_node -> rules = rules;
  new_node -> next = next;
  return new_node;
} 
void storetgt(char* line){
  int argcp = 0;
  char** args = arg_parse(line,&argcp);
  if(strcmp(args[0], "a:") == 0){
    create(args[0],NULL,NULL);
  }else if(strcmp(args[0], "b:") == 0){
    create(args[0],NULL,NULL);
  }else if(strcmp(args[0], "c:") == 0){
    create(args[0],NULL,NULL);
  }
}
void storerules(char* line){
  int argcp;
  char** args = arg_parse(line,&argcp);
  if(line[0] == '\t'){
    storerules(&line[1]);
  } else {
    if(strcmp(args[0], "echo") == 0 && strcmp(args[1], "a") == 0){
      createrules(args, NULL);
    }else if(strcmp[0], "echo") == 0 && strcmp(args[1], "b") == 0){
      createrules(args, NULL);
    }else if(strcmp[0], "echo") == 0 && strcmp(args[1], "c") == 0){
      createrules(args, NULL);
    }
  }
}//ags is pointer to array of characters that holds arguments.
```

What this seems to be doing is creating bunch of separate nodes that holds different tgt name and another bunch of separate nodes that holds different rules. How can I make it so that tgt node that holds [A:] points to the node that contains [echo A] and so that tgt node that holds [B:] points to the node that contains [echo B] and so on?

Comment: Make sure you copy the names into the `tgt` structures so that when your next input overwrites the previous input, it doesn't rewrite the stored data.  That probably means dynamic memory allocation and copying (or using `strdup()`), rather than simply storing pointers.

Comment: `size_t = bufsize = 0;`?? maybe `size_t bufsize = 0;`?

Comment: There is only *one* `linelen = getline(&line, &bufsize, makefile);` , and it is *not* inside the loop.